# How do we take advantage of automatically adjusted inset if the ViewController is created programatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

In IOS 7, Apple automatically adjust inset to the viewController.

This works if we specify the viewController in XIB.

What about if we create the viewController programatically?

How would we specify that the scrollView is the one where we want the inset to be adjusted?

In fact, how do we adjust the inset ourself?

This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionView * cv = (UICollectionView *)self.view; //The collection view is self.view
    cv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clBackGroundColor];
    [cv registerClass:[BGCollectionViewCellImage class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:[BGCollectionViewCellImage reuseIdentifier]];
    BOOL autoInset = self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets;//auto inset is yes
    while(false);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Actually I wonder how automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets doesn't work on that one given that the scrollVIew is self.view and clearly self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is YES